# How do I create "groups of users" and set permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know the names of the SQL statements that will be able to perform the following to my database:

- Create a group of users that will allow them to only SELECT from Table 1, but be able to SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT INTO Tables 2 and 3;
- Create another group of users that will allow them to SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT INTO all three of the aforementioned tables

All three of the tables are in the same database.

May someone please provide some sample code so that I can accomplish something like that? Thanks!

Comment: Ready ["Server-Level roles"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15) and/or ["Database-level roles"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15). If you then have a **specific** question ask that one. But I suggest to post on [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com) then. It seems to better fit there.

Comment: On prem SQL Server and Azure SQL Server have different syntax for this issue.

Comment: Answered in duplicate on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291336/how-do-i-create-groups-of-users-and-set-permissions-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all, create the groups you want on the `computer management`  from `Users And Groups`.**

`SqlGroup1` with the role `[db_datareader]` for the `online_market` database and only read permission from the `groups` table

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup1] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
CREATE USER [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup1] FOR LOGIN [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup1]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup1]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON Groups TO [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup1]
go
DENY update,insert,delete ON OBJECT::Groups TO [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup1];  
GO
```

`SqlGroup2` with the **role** `[db_datareader]` and `[db_datawriter]` for the `online_market` database and `select,insert,update,delete` permission from `the groups table`

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup2] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
CREATE USER [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup2] FOR LOGIN [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup2]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup2]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup2]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup2]
GO
GRANT select,update,insert,delete ON Groups TO [DESKTOP-5GJ89H1\SqlGroup2]
GO
```

Now define normal users. This section is not in question

`User1` with the password `12345678` and the **role** `[db_datareader]` for the `online_market` database and only read permission from `the groups table`

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [user1] WITH PASSWORD=N'12345678' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
CREATE USER [user1] FOR LOGIN [user1]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [user1]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [user1]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON Groups TO [user1]
go
DENY update,insert,delete ON OBJECT::Groups TO [user1];  
GO
```

`User2` with the password `12345678` and the **role** `[db_datareader]` and `[db_datawriter]` for the `online_market` database and `select,insert,update,delete` permission from `the groups table`

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [user2] WITH PASSWORD=N'12345678' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
CREATE USER [user2] FOR LOGIN [user2]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [user2]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [user2]
GO
USE [online_market]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [user2]
GO
GRANT select,update,insert,delete ON Groups TO [user2]
GO
```